# Unable to find resource in JUnit test in Maven multi-module project

Tags: java, maven, junit, classpath

I'm using Maven 3.0.3, JUnit 4.8.1, and Java 1.6.  I have this in a JUnit test file ...

```
@Before
public void loadTestProps() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException { 
    final InputStream in = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test.properties");
    testProps = new Properties();
    testProps.load(in);
```

"test.properties" is not getting picked up (the input stream object is null).  My project structure is as follows:

parent
+ --- pom.xml
+ --- war module
+ ------ pom.xml
+ ------ src/test/java/JUnit file
+ ------ src/test/resources/test.properties
+ --- ear module
+ ------- pom.xml

I would prefer to keep my "src/test/resources" directory within my WAR module, since the test only pertains to the WAR file.  Is there a way I can rewrite the above Java to find my "test.properties" or do I have to move the file out of the WAR module?

Comment: Is src/test/resources defined as being a source folder?

Comment: That ought to work just fine. Is the test failing in both your IDE and the command line? Are you sure there are no typos anywhere?

Comment: Can we see the pom.xml for your war module?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 
    getResourceAsStream("test.properties");
you should use 
    getResourceAsStream("/test.properties");